# Server unresponsive, messages shown on console but not in log files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, troubleshooting, rsyslog

I'm using Ubuntu Server 10.04.4, and once in a while the server hangs (once a month) and is totally unresponsive. The tty is flooded with messages like [these](http://pastebin.com/zV4seKt9). The problem is that these messages are not in my log files after reboot. How to log these messages so that I can analyze them later? In the current logs I can't see anything that would tell me why this is happening.

I would also appreciate if anybody can tell from those messages what's going on. This server is a guest virtual machine. The host server is also Ubuntu server 10.04 with KVM/QEMU.

Answer (score 1):

As @coredump (very relevant user name!) pointed out, that's the tail end of a kernel panic.
Doubt those are going to be logged anywhere. Maybe you can enable a crash memory dump, I've never done that, though.

**Edit:**
For kernel crash dumps, it seems [kdump is currently the way to go](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_use_kdump_to_debug_kernel_crashes).

You can configure the kernel to automatically reboot on panic with `echo 10 > /proc/sys/kernel/panic` (reboot after 10 seconds on panic), although that obviously doesn't solve the problem. ;-)

Comment: That's actually a nice tip. But as you said, it doesn't solve the problem :)

Comment: I added a link to kdump, which should allow you to grab the crash dump.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can save those messages in log. Usually that happens because the kernel broke so badly that it can't even write the messages at that state.

Take a picture/screenshot, is what I do usually.